# Submitting multiple rows in gridview with Checkboxes (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am aiming to get data:

- From an sql database
- To a gridview
- To a local table

So far, I am able to use a stored procedure to display the sql data to a gridvew and I am also able to use checkboxes to send the data to a local table.

Issue:
Only one row's data is being submitted to the table, despite the number of checkboxes checked.

ex. I click 3 checkboxes, wanting to get 3 different rows of data to the table. I hit the submit button and when I check the table, only one of the "checked" rows is submitted to the table 3 times.

EDITED Code:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localDataB"].ConnectionString;

        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            string insertStatement = "INSERT into LocalDB (Item1, Item2, Item3)" + "(@Item1, @Item2, @Item3)";

            string Data1, Data2;
            float Data3;

            foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
            {

                CheckBox ckSel = (gRow.FindControl("checker") as CheckBox);
                if (ckSel.Checked)
                {
                    Data1 = Convert.ToString(gRow.Cells[1].Text);
                    Data2 = Convert.ToString(gRow.Cells[2].Text);
                    Data3 = Convert.ToInt32(gRow.Cells[3].Text);

                    using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(insertStatement, sqlConnection))
                    {
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("Item1", SqlDbType.Text).Value = Data1;
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("Item2", SqlDbType.Text).Value = Data2;
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("Item3", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Data3;
                        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        GVbind();
```

Code for checkbox inside grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Data Found" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" DataKeyNames="Data1" Width="70%" Visible="False" ShowFooter="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="SelectBox" runat="server" Text="Select"></asp:Label>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="checker" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="checker_CheckedChanged"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Data1" HeaderText="Title1" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Data2" HeaderText="Title2" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Data3" HeaderText="Title3" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it not at all clear what your routine checker_CheckedChanged() does?

You don't need a post-back or anything for the check boxes - but ONLY the one submit button and code stub

. Those data1, data2 etc. will NOT persist in memory anyway. So, you can't use that  routine - but you don't need it either.

Unless the grid has multiple pages etc., then dump that routine. You are free to check box any row in the grid. You then have one submit button code, and that routine just needs a bit of change to check all GV rows, and save the check box values.

That submit button code thus can/will look like this:

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localDataB"].ConnectionString;

        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            // insert any row with check boxes into temp db

            string insertStatement = "INSERT into LocalDB (Item1, Item2, Item3) " + 
                                     "values (@Item1, @Item2, @Item3)";

            bool Data1, Data2, Data3;

            foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                Data1 = Convert.ToBoolean(gRow.Cells[0].ToString());
                Data2 = Convert.ToBoolean(gRow.Cells[1].ToString());
                Data3 = Convert.ToBoolean(gRow.Cells[2].ToString());

                // save data if ANY is checked
                if (Data1 | Data2 | Data3)
                {
                    using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(insertStatement, sqlConnection))
                    {
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Item1", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Data1;
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Item2", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Data2;
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Item3", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Data3;
                        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    GVbind();
    }
```

I don't see the need for your first routine. The submit button can loop the GV, get the check box values, and if any one of the 3 is checked, then you do the insert.

However, keep in mind that the cells[] collection ONLY works for datafields if you using a templated control and  REAL check box, then you need to use findcontrol, and NOT the cells[] collection

## Edit:

Ok, first, information provided suggests that a template field is being used.

HOWEVER, we will first address the CheckBoxField code, since it HARD  to google and find that answer. So I going to include that answer.

If a check box is a datafield, then you can't change/edit, but you STILL MAY want to iterate over the GV, and get those values.

So, for data fields, say like this:

```
<asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" />
```

Then our code has to work like this (you have to dig deeper into cells() colleciton.

So, code becomes this:

```
          foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                Data1 =(gRow.Cells[0].Controls[0] as CheckBox).Checked;
                Data2 = (gRow.Cells[1].Controls[0] as CheckBox).Checked;
                Data3 = (gRow.Cells[2].Controls[0] as CheckBox).Checked;
```

Note how a CheckBoxField requires us to use controls.

However, as noted, with template field (any kind and ANY of them?).

WE DO NOT use the Cells[] collection and templated columns DO NOT appear in the cells collection.

And thus, in a lot (probably most) cases, then we can expect to have a CheckBox control dropped into the markup as a templated field.

Typical looks like this:

```
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" class="table borderhide" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"   HeaderText="FirstName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"    HeaderText="LastName"   />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City"        HeaderText="City"       />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName"   HeaderText="HotelName" HeaderStyle-Width="200"   />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Smoking"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSmoking" runat="server"
                            Checked='<%# Eval("Smoking") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Balcony"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBalcony" runat="server" 
                            Checked='<%# Eval("Balcony") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

So in above, the first values (bound fields) WILL BE found in cells colleciton.

However, the templated fields above? we have to do this:

```
                           "WHERE ID = @ID";
            foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox cSmoke = (CheckBox)gRow.FindControl("chkSmoking");
                CheckBox cBlacony = (CheckBox)gRow.FindControl("chkBalcony");
                int PKID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];

                using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
                {
                    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@S", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = cSmoke.Checked;
                    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@B", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = cBlacony.Checked;
                    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PKID;
                    cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

So, our code then becomes this:

```
            foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                Data1 =(gRow.FindControl("Active") as CheckBox).Checked;
                Data2 = (gRow.FindControl("Smoking") as CheckBox).Checked;
                Data3 = (gRow.FindControl("Balcony") as CheckBox).Checked;
```

Now of course, you replace the "Text control" id with YOUR data 1, 2, and 3 id that you used.

The rest of the code should be the same.

BIG LESSON OF THE DAY?

Post a wee bit of markup - not a huge boatload - but just a few lines next time. You save world poverty, and I would have been able to post a better answer next time.

So the rule is:

DataBound fields - use cells[] collection.

Templated fields - you have to using .FindControl("name of control id goes here")

## Edit#2

Ok, so far, the question is now this:

We have some data. If the user checks the row 1, or 5 or 10 rows, for each of the checked rows, I want to write out the columns/values I have in 3 other columns item1, item2, item3?

Simple queston!!!!

Ok, so the ONLY missing information is WHAT data type field type is item1, item2, and item3? We only really are missing that part.

So, if check box = true, write out those 3 item columns to the new temp table.

So, the code now should be:

```
            bool Data1, Data2, Data3;

            foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                // get check box - 

                CheckBox ckSel = (gRow.FindControl("checker") as CheckBox);

                // save data if ANY is checked
                if (ckSel.Checked)
                {
                    Data1 = Convert.ToBoolean(gRow.Cells[0].Text);
                    Data2 = Convert.ToBoolean(gRow.Cells[1].Text);
                    Data3 = Convert.ToBoolean(gRow.Cells[2].Text);

                    using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(insertStatement, sqlConnection))
                    {
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Item1", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Data1;
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Item2", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Data2;
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Item3", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Data3;
                        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
```

As noted, I stated MULTIPLE TIMES NOW, that non templated columns STILL MUST use cells collection. ONLY templated columns can and need to use FindControl. All others MUST continue to use .Cells[] collection.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've used your code and the app runs with no errors. Also, you are right, the first routine is redundant, I'm glad you showed me that. 
However, after selecting the checkboxes and pressing the submit button I get this error at this line: `Data1 = Convert.ToBoolean(gRow.Cells[0].ToString());` "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean."

Comment: As I stated, the cells collection only works for datafields. But if you have REAL check boxes, (templated fields, then you need to use find control - and not use cells[] collection.  I was RATHER VERY clear on this issue. So, are you using CheckBoxField, or a templated field with  standard CheckBox control inside of that templated field?

Comment: I am using a template field with standard Checkbox inside of it.

Comment: See my edit and additional information -

Comment: Thank you, I have added your code and it starts up with no errors. However, when I check the checkboxes and click submit, I get the following error for the line `Data1 = (gRow.FindControl("Item1") as CheckBox).Checked;` "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
(... as System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox) returned null." I have also updated the question to better represent your input and how my Gridview actually looks.

Comment: You ONLY have one check box. So If I check 5 rows, then which of Data1-3 columns am I to update or change???? I would assume you need/want 3 check boxes per row?

Comment: The stored procedure I use populates the grid depending on the what is put in the textbox. When I put the checkbox in the template, it populates a checkbox for each row. Although the number of rows varies, there are only 3 columns where data is populate but 5 columns in total: The grid columns look like this: [checkbox][Item1][Item2][Item3][Edit button]

Comment: Right, so say there is 10 rows displayed. I check the box for the first 3 rows - where is that value and which of the 3 items am I to update??? If there is some txtBox that controls which of the item 1-3 I am supposed to set, then fine, but then we need logic to decide which item1-3 we are to update then, right? I don't see that logic? How do we decide which item1-3 to update based on one check box?

Comment: Ah, I think I grasp this. If you have a check box, then write out item1, item2, item3 to the new temp table for checked rows - simple - see my edit#2 - I post how that code should work. But you still missed out and did not follow that rule - the rule was findcontrol for templated columns, and STILL to use cells() for non templated columns.

Comment: The code starts successfully, however when I select the checkboxes and click submit I get the error "String was not recognized as a valid" on the line `Data1 = Convert.ToBoolean(gRow.Cells[1].Text);`. I have updated the code in the question to include your changes. As for th type of data being used, in the local database, Item1 and Item2 are of data type NVARCHAR and Item3 is of type FLOAT.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't put in the full error: "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean"

Comment: When looking at the grid, what do the 3 bound fields Item1-3 show for their text? If you using Boundcheckboxfield, then you have to use Cells[column here].Controls[0], and cast to checkbox - but you have DataBound field, then Cells[x].Text should work - so what does the text show for Item1-3??? Might be nulls in those for some rows???

Comment: From the design view the columns that are tied to Item1-3 are have the text "Databound" for each of its rows. I do not believe there are nulls becuase I was previously able to write to my local table from using the checkboxs. The issue is that only one checked checkbox could be read. The source view of the grid can be seen in the updated question.

Comment: Right, and when the grid displays, what do you see for the item1-3 values? We are assuming the text displayed in that grid for item1-3 is True or False - else how we going to covert what you see in those columns to a bol true/false then? Is there some other text that displays? So when viewing the grid, we have item1-3 and one check box on each row. If row is checked box = true, then we want to write out item1-3 values to the temp table. So, nulls might be a issue, but MORE important is what is the text values currently displaying? (we assume true/false for those 3 item values, right????

Comment: in other words, what is the data type of for the 3 columns item1-3?

Comment: I apologize, I misunderstood the question. I will explain how my grid is supposed to work: I have a database of objects. Each Object has a Label [Item1], description [Item2], and quantity [Item3]. Using the stored procedure, whenever I search certain terms, the grid will populate with however many objects fit those terms. So the grid will have any number of rows, but the same 3 columns for [Item1, Item2, Item3] and a fourth column for the checkbox. I want to be able to select any number of checkboxes so that the Object's Item1-3 will be stored into a local database...

Comment: ...The local database stores Item1 and Item2 as NVARCHAR and Item3 as FLOAT.

Comment: then those 3 values are not Boolean at all, and thus it makes ZERO sense to be converting them to bol's then, right? We have to and want to and need to of course define Item1-3 as the correct data type vars then. So, we change Item1, and Item2 to string, and Item3 to a type of float then. So, we can dump trying to covert two strings to a bol, and float to a bol. So Item1, Item2, Item3 have to be defined as NOT Boolean, but the correct data variable types that they are expected to be. So define Item1, and Item2 as string, and Item3 as float. And then correct the sqldb.type in the pramaters.add

Comment: I have updated the code to your specifications, however I am unsure of the proper format for float in the line `Data3 = Convert.ToInt32(gRow.Cells[3].Text);` How it is now is what I thought would work but it give me the error "Input string was not in a correct format.'" Data3 doesn't have to be float, I could change it to Int if it works better. Please let me know if that should be done.

Comment: The database doesn't have float numbers, it was only float now because a tutorial I found used that as an example, I was planning on changing it later after getting the gridview to write to the database. I can change it to Int without comprising the intended function of the application.

Comment: Ok great. I perhaps was a but harsh, but it seemed that after spending significant time on how important data types are that my advice was being 100% ignored, and thus I was wasting my time and in fact wasting your time. So if a int is ok, then declare that var as int and that convert to should work.

Comment: I have changed the local database to take Int. But I'm still unsure of how to convert Int here: `Data3 = Convert.ToInt32(gRow.Cells[3].Text);` I thought this was the way but I get the error "Input string was not in a correct format". It starts up fine but gives this error when I try to submit checkboxes. Also is this the correct way to type this?: `sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("Item3", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Data3;` I have not gotten errors for it but I just want to make sure.

Comment: I couldn't find out how to properly write those lines so I managed to combine my starting code with your code and even the suggestion by the other user (Avantha Siriwardana), and got the application to work properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this;

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item1", data1);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item2", data2);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item3", data3);
```